# Disable multiple date ranges with jquery ui calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I'm using the Jquery ui calendar to show a 12 month calendar. I am currently disabling dates using:

```
    var array = ["1/12/2016", "11/12/2016", "12/12/2016", "13/12/2016", "14/12/2016", "15/12/2016", "16/12/2016"];
```

with:

```
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
    var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', date);
        return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
    }
```

I need to disable multiple different date ranges, so need to use something like:

```
    var array = [ { "from": "2/12/2016", "to": "8/12/2016" }, { "from": "11/12/2016", "to": "16/12/2016" } ];
```

Anyone have any ideas how this can be done? Tried to find solutions online but with no joy - i can provide full code on JSfiddle if needed.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare the `date` in every iteration of the `beforeShowDay` function, you have to get your "boudaries" *(`from` and `to` of each disabled ranges)* and format it as a date object.

It can then be compared with the `date` of the iteration, which already is a date object.

A `for` loop will then compare the `date` with each ranges you defined and return a true or false.

**Notice** that there is a second argument to be returned, which is a `class` to apply.
Just to demonstrate, I applyed the `red` class to disabled dates.
If you do not want to apply a specific class to it, just return an empty string.

```js
// An array of objects containing disabled date ranges
var disabledArr = [ { "from": "2/12/2016", "to": "8/12/2016" }, { "from": "11/12/2016", "to": "16/12/2016" } ];


$("#calendar").datepicker({
    numberOfMonths: [4,3],
    
    // May be used to "force" the 12 months calendar to display 2016
    //minDate: new Date(2016, 1 -1, 1),
    //maxDate: new Date(2016, 12 -1, 31),

    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        //console.log(date);

        // For each calendar date, check if it is within a disabled range.
        for(i=0;i<disabledArr.length;i++){
            // Get each from/to ranges
            var From = disabledArr[i].from.split("/");
            var To = disabledArr[i].to.split("/");
            // Format them as dates : Year, Month (zero-based), Date
            var FromDate = new Date(From[2],From[1]-1,From[0]);
            var ToDate = new Date(To[2],To[1]-1,To[0]);

            // Set a flag to be used when found
            var found=false;
            // Compare date
            if(date>=FromDate && date<=ToDate){
                found=true;
                return [false, "red"]; // Return false (disabled) and the "red" class.
            }
        }
        
        //At the end of the for loop, if the date wasn't found, return true.
        if(!found){
            return [true, ""]; // Return true (Not disabled) and no class.
        }
    }
});
```

```css
.red span{
    background-color:red !important;
    color:white !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="calendar"></div>
```

Here is a [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/MbqYYO?editors=0010) to play with.